# What is the significance of the right lower node in a 12-lead electrocardiogram placement?

Tags: cardiology, electricity, electrocardiogram, limbs

Given this [EKG limb leads image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Limb_leads_of_EKG.png), I noticed that the function of the right leg node in a 12-lead ecg/ekg is missing.

In an actual placement I know this is present.

So I need to ask, what is the significance of this node?
Does it serve as an electrical ground?